# Symfony 3 forms: add a new field+data on PRE_SUBMIT event listener

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to add a field and give it a data using an event listener. The value **of new data depends on the data of other submitted fields** in the same form, so I''m using `PRE_SUBMIT`. I didn't try it on `Symfony 2`, so I don't know if the result is the same also.

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) { 
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $form->add('country', null, array('data' => 'españa'));


        });
   }
```

The problem: the new data (country) is never persisted. What am I doing wrong?

Here you have the `Task` entity:

```
class Task
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="name", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="country", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $country;

    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $country
     *
     * @return Manufacturer
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Manufacturer
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear (to me). What I understand: you have your form in the browser, you do some selection on that form, and according to the selection made (without reloading the page), one of the form input field, `country` in that case, should have its content automaticaly updated according to the content of the other filled out fields. Is my understanding correct? If it is so, I think you need to use some javascript in your twig template file to do that because Symfony won't achieve dynamic update of the view on client side.

Comment: I want to add the new field/data on the server (inside the `Event listener`). There is no select. On the original form there is just the field `name` (for example will be `This is a new task Ref.:347`). Dependindg on the value of `Ref` (as you can see, the last element on the string)  the field `country` will be assigned a value or other inside the `Event listener`.

Comment: something weird to me when I check at similar work on my side: you have `$form->add('country', null, array('data' => 'españa'));` and I would have rather written: `$form->add('country', TextType::class, array('data' => 'españa'));` with `use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;` on top of the file.

Comment: @nyluje thanks, I did what you said, but the `country`'s value is still not saved..

Comment: if you do           `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA` instead of `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` does the value get saved? Then you have the field country displaying on your form and you don't want that?

Comment: Yes, I want to give a value to country, **but** will depend on the submitted name's value.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT (OR SUBMIT), function (FormEvent $event) { 
                 dump($form);
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $form->getNormData()['country'] = 'espana';
                 dump($form);


}
```

If it is not correct yet, look at the dump($form) outcome before and after inside the function and pin down where you can change the value of your model as you wish.